# Why is the data type needed in pointer declarations?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

As far as I know about data types in C/C++, while declaring a variable, we need to declare its data type, which tells the compiler to reserve the number of bytes in the memory accordingly.

But in the case of pointers, we know that their size is constant (eg. 2 bytes in "Turbo Compiler"), irrespective of the data type *of the variable it is pointing to*, because the pointer is storing a memory address as an unsigned integer.

My question is, if the pointers are *always* a constant size in bytes, then what is the need of mentioning the **data type** while declaring them? Is my understanding about pointers wrong?

Comment: What's the point of *not* specifying a data type? If you plan to do anything with the pointer at all, then you need to know the data type it points to.

Comment: @Chandra : What about (void *) ?

Comment: @tenfour you might want to perform the same kind of operation on the pointer's destination regardless of the type

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The data type is needed when **dereferencing the pointer** so it knows how much data it should read. For example dereferencing a `char` pointer should read the next byte from the address it is pointing to while an `int` pointer should read 2 bytes.

Comment: That's a great answer! I've finally understood that.

Comment: Simple yet intuitive explanation.

Comment: Makes sense, great answer!

Comment: Good but not complete answer.

Comment: I don't think this is quite correct. You can declare a class, and then declare a pointer to that class, without giving a definition of the class. The pointer would be a pointer to an incomplete type, but the compiler allows you to do this.

Answer (score 23):

Data type of a pointer is needed in two situations:

1. Dereferencing the pointer
2. Pointer arithmetic

How it is used in **dereferencing the pointer**?
Consider the following example:

```
    {
        char *k; //poniter of type char
        short j=256;
        k=&j;    // Obviously You have to ignore the warnings
        printf("%d",*k)
    }
```

Now because k is of type `char` so it will only read one byte. Now binary value of `256` is `0000000100000000` but because k is of type `char` so it will read only the first byte hence the output will be 0. 
**Note**: if we assign j=127 then the output will be 127 because 127 will be held by the first byte.  
Now come to **pointer arithmetic**: 
Consider the following example:

```
    {
        short *ptr;
        short k=0;
        ptr=&k;
        k++;
        ptr++;// pointer arithmetic
    }
```

Are statements `k++` and `ptr++` are same thing? No, `k++` means `k=k+1` and `ptr++` means `ptr=ptr+2`. Because the compiler "knows" this is a pointer and that it points to a short, it adds 2 to ptr instead of 1, so the pointer "points to" the next integer. 
For more info refer second chapter of [this](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2012/readings/pointers.pdf) tutorial.

Comment: I don't think this is correct because the compiler allows you to have pointers to incomplete types. E.g. you can have a pointer to a class that you have only declared but haven't defined.

Answer (score 7):

First of all the size and representation of the pointers themselves [aren't always the same for different types](http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html). It's just something that happens on many implementations.

Second, when using pointers you don't care about the size of the pointers themselves. You need **the size of the pointed type**.

For example, try this:

```
int var[5];
char *c = (char *)var;
int  *x = var;

printf("%p\n%p\n", p + 1, x + 1);
```

You'll see pointer arithmetic strongly depends on the size of the pointed type.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not about pointer size but pointer dereferencing. (wether in C or C++)

Say you have:

```
int* someint;
float* somefloat;
```

`*someint` references a memory size of `sizeof(int)`, whereas `*somefloat` references a memory size of `sizeof(float)` which are different.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that this code compiles without error (as you would like):

```
int a;
int b = 42;
void * d = &b;

a = *d;
```

What should be the value of a?

Now with this one:

```
int a;
float b = 42.0;
void * d = &b;

a = *d;
```

What do you expect in a?

Actually the type specifies how should the pointed area be interpreted. You should specify `int *` in the first example and `float *` in the second one, instead of `void *`.

Comment: This answer is the perfect complement to the top answer, does a really good job of illustrating the practical need for it via example.

Answer (score 2):

What size a pointer needs depends on the system you are using. On a `x86_64` system the pointer size might by 64 bit.

The reason why you need the data type for pointers is because the compiler has to know what the size of the memory cell is, among others, the pointer is pointing to. Also type safety cannot be ensured w/o the type. Also, you would have to typecast every pointer when accessing structures from the pointer.

You also could use a `void` pointer and do everything by hand. But why should you want that?

Answer (score 1):

Data types are needed simply for type checking.

Comment: In general, try to give answers that are a little more substantial. Perhaps try to include an example?

Answer (score 0):

it is the concept of a strong typing used in c++. the size of the pointer may be the same but the size of the pointed type may differ. you can always cast a pointer of one type into a pointer of another type however.